# opening a file by double clicking

Tags: java, javafx-2

I saw a video tutorial about making a video player in javafx. In that tutorial the path to the video file was set in the program code itself. I searched a lot to find some tutorial to pass the path to the file at runtime by double clicking  it, like, we always double click on a video file to open it in windows media player or any other similar program.  All the file based programs I come across is setting the path in the code itself.   How can I make my program to receive the path to the file at runtime or from the operating system? Can anyone suggest me a good tutorial

Comment: This is a feature of the OS (more specifically the desktop) not of your program. Are you an Windows or on Linux?

Comment: Usually, the File explorer passes the path name as part of the command line you have provided for that sort of file.

Comment: @Henry I am using Windows7 32 bit

Comment: @Henry can You tell me how can I make my program ready to accept the path passed by the operating system. Is there any api for this in java?

Comment: The program must accept the file name as a parameter that is passed into `main`. In the OS you need to associate the file extension with your program.

Comment: @Henry, that means my program can receive the path through the String[] args array , Right?

Comment: @sony yes, this is correct.